How to create a Google Maps intent including waypoints in Android Auto / Android Automotive
This API allows mobile Android apps to send Intents to Google Maps with several waypoints.
Uri mapIntentUri =
Uri.parse(
    "google.navigation:q=Port+Macquarie+NSW"
        + "&waypoints=-32.9599188%2C151.6240806%7C-31.9432539%2C152.4699808"
        + "&waypoint_types=1%7C1"
        + "&waypoint_names=ChargePoint+Charging+Station%7CEvie+Charging+Station"
        + "&waypoint_power_outputs_kw=6.6%7C350");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, mapIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);

Unfortunately this code doesn't work in Android Auto. I managed to adapt the code a bit like this and was able to send the intent to Google Maps:
val mapUri = Uri.parse(url)
val mapIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, mapUri)                
mapIntent.setPackage(ExternalMapNavigationOption.GoogleMaps.androidPackageName)
mapIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
carContext.startActivity(mapIntent)

However, this code seems to have a few issues in Android Auto:

It only works the first time it is launched.
The waypoints are ignored.

Is there a way to do this properly in Android Auto?
